# How to make a main div appear next to a sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basic generic web page with a photo gallery as practice here, but for some reason I cannot get the gallery div to float next to the sidebar div so that there isn't a big empty space above it. Floating them just destroys everything. When I inspect element it shows that there's a margin taking up all of the space to the right of the sidebar/above to the gallery, but I've looked through my css over and over and can't find where that margin could be coming from. I'm not 100% sure that's what is causing the issue though.

If anyone knows how I can make this position correctly it would be much appreciated. I feel like I've tried everything and I'm just not getting it.

Here is the link to the code on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/laurynm/h6mu6hsb/

```
.gallery {
    width: 80%; 
    position: relative;

}

#sidebar {
    position: relative;
    width: 230px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a stab in the dark, and made [a jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/tk2z944t/) for you to try out. In essence, I gathered different sections in wrappers, converted them to `inline-block`, and hope it looks kinda like what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/h6mu6hsb/4/

```
#sidebar {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 230px;
}
```

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that floating it just messes it up. It was resolved using inline:block though.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this so you dont have horizontal scrolling problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/espriella/fdmdwpp5/

Using display as table-cell

.sidebar{

```
min-width: 200px;
display: table-cell;
```

}
.gallery{

```
display: table-cell;
width: 100%;
```

}